# Obtain a first order DE for a Bessel function of order $n$

Tags: bessel-functions

An exercise in my textbook is the following: 
Let $J_n (z)$ denote the Bessel function of order n. Set 
$$\theta(z,t)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}J_{n}(z)t^n$$
and assume that the series converges.

Obtain a **first** order DE relating $\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial z}$ and $\theta(z,t)$.

I hope anybody can help, because I am totally stuck at this moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial z}=\sum_m J'_m(z)t^m$$
Now using the [derivative properties for the Bessel function](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.6.E1), one has
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial z}=\frac{1}{2}\sum \left[J_{m-1}(z)-J_{m+1}(z)\right]t^m
\end{equation}
It remains to shift the index $m$ in the summations to obtain
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial z}=\frac{1}{2}\left[t\sum_m J_m(z)t^m-\frac{1}{t}\sum_m J_m(z)t^m\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left( t-\frac{1}{t} \right)\theta(z,t)
\end{align}
Actually, $\theta$ is a [generating function](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.12.E1) for the Bessel functions.

Comment: This is really helpful! and can we say that: $\theta(z,t)= e^{(1/2)z(t-1/t)}$

Comment: Yes, this is the expression of a [generating function for the Bessel functions](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.12.E1).

Comment: If I may add a second part. if we set $t=e^{i\theta}$ and also $t=-e^{i\theta}$, how can we say that for complex z: $sin(z sin \theta) = 2\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}J_{2n+1}(z) sin(2n+1)\theta$

Comment: Why don't you mention $\frac{\partial}{\partial z} \theta(z,t) = f(t) \theta(z,t)$ means $\theta(z,t) = \theta(0,t) e^{z f(t)}$

Comment: Sorry, that was clear for me, but the question was to construct an ODE. The remark on the generating function in the comment was made to give a reference to the asker.